# Why do opposite angles have equal cosines?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: http://oi47.tinypic.com/nv1pbs.jpg]

Why is $x$ in Figure 1 $x$ and not $-x$? This has caused me to not understand why $\cos(-\theta) = x$ and $\cos(\theta) = x$.

Comment: That's just sloppy drafting of the figure. For the angles shown, the cosine is indeed negative.

Comment: because $x$ is the projection of the point $(x,y)$ over the X-axis, wich represent $\cos\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point has co-ordinates $(x,y)$. In the diagram, $x$ is a negative number, but that's OK - variables are allowed to stand for negative numbers. The angle $\theta$ is in the second quadrant, where the cosine function is negative, so $\cos\theta=x$ is perfectly consistent.

Comment: I understood the OP's problem as being that the diagram seems to claim that the _length_ of the line segment between the origin and $(\cos\theta,0)$ is $x$ -- but actually it is $|x|$, which in this case equals $-x$.

Comment: @Henning, you might be right.